# How to reach to a subelement using other subelements MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am using C# ASP.Net to reach MongoDB.

Let's say I have the element in the database below.

```cs
var guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var temp = new BsonDocument
{
    {"Name", name},
    {"Surname", surname},
    {"Email", email},
    {"URL", guid}
};
```

Where name, surname, email and guid are all strings.

What I am trying to do is to reach to "Name", "Surname" and "Email" values of this element by using this object's "URL" to find it in the database or use its "Name", "Surname" and "Email" to reach its guid.

In other words, what I am trying to do is to use `.Find(guid)` function (Or another function if this process cannot be done with `.Find()` function) to search the object with its guid and then take that object's "Name", "Surname" and "Email" values.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem with the code below.
Let's give value to all variables  to make it easier to understand

```cs
name = "John"
surname = "Doe"
email = "johndoe@example.com"
```

```cs
var search = new BsonDocument
{
    {"URL", guid}
};
var result = collectionName.Find(search).ToList();
string name = result[0].ElementAt(1).ToString();
string surname = result[0].ElementAt(2).ToString();
string email = result[0].ElementAt(3).ToString();
```

Which returns the values as follows:

```cs
name = "Name=John"
surname = "Surname=Doe"
email = "Email=johndoe@example.com"
```

By using `.Substring()` function it is possible to get rid of unwanted parts of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the find() method will (by default) return the entire document. If it only returned the fields you queried for, the find() method would be quite useless.

I'm not familiar with C#, but in the shell or in NodeJS you would run:

```
.find({ URL: "12345" })
```

This would retrieve all documents were the URL field is "12345".

To retrieve all documents where the name is "Alex", run:

```
.find({ Name: "Alex" })
```

Comment: That's not what I was trying to ask, sorry if I wasn't clear, let me rephrase. Only known data is this element's guid, so I am trying to reach to this element's name, surname and email using its guid. Basically, I am trying to find the owner of the guid input.

Comment: @KorMoon maybe showing us what you have already tried might make your question more clear to people. even if it's pseudocode.